# The curse of the \n character in C

Tags: c, character

I've made a simple spellchecker that reads in a dictionary and user text file to check against it. The program needs to display the line and word index of any word not in the dictionary. So it works fine until the user text file has a return `\n` character in it (at the end of a paragraph or sentence). So Hello is actually tested against the dictionary as `Hello\n` and the program believes its spelled incorrectly. Can anyone advise a method to remove the `\n` character? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void StrLower(char str[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        str[i] = (char)tolower(str[i]);
    }

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *fpDict, *fpWords;

    fpWords = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if((fpDict = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("No dictionary file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char dictionaryWord[50]; // current word read from dictionary
    char line[100]; // line read from spell check file (max 50 chars)
    int isWordfound = 0; // 1 if word found in dictionary
    int lineCount = 0; // line in spellcheck file we are currently on
    int wordCount = 0; // word on line of spellcheck file we are currently on

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fpWords ) != NULL )
    { 
        lineCount ++;
        wordCount = 0;
        char *spellCheckWord;
        spellCheckWord = strtok(line, " ");
        while (spellCheckWord != NULL) {
            wordCount++;
            spellCheckWord = strtok(NULL, " ,");

            if(spellCheckWord==NULL)
                continue;

            StrLower(spellCheckWord);
            printf("'%s'\n", spellCheckWord);


            while(!feof(fpDict))
            { 
                fscanf(fpDict,"%s",dictionaryWord);
                int res = strcmp(dictionaryWord, spellCheckWord);

                if(res==0)
                {
                    isWordfound = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!isWordfound){
                printf("word '%s' not found in Dictionary on line: %d, word index: %d\n", spellCheckWord, lineCount, wordCount); //print word and line not in dictionary
            }


            rewind(fpDict); //resets dictionarry file pointer 
            isWordfound = 0; //resets wordfound for next iteration

        }
    }

    fclose(fpDict);
    fclose(fpWords);
    return 0;
}
```

Wow thanks for the quick responses everyone. You guys are great, over the moon with that!

Comment: This is out of the scope of the question, but your code is wrong: it does not check the first word of a line, and that's because you're tokenizing (using strtok) again before a word check. You should do it after the check, at the end of the loop where strtok is currently.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the '\n' Immediately after the `fgets()` call:

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fpWords ) != NULL )
{
    size_t linelen = strlen(line);
    assert((linelen > 0) && "this can happen only when file is binary");
    if (line[linelen - 1] == '\n') line[--linelen] = 0; /* remove trailing '\n' and update linelen */
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding \n to the argument you pass to strtok.

Comment: Or, if `strtok` were ditched (not always necessary, but I personally never use it), use `isspace` (or possibly `!isalpha`) to avoid any further whitespace clashes.

Comment: `strtok(line, "\n")` will not remove the `'\n'` from `line` if `line` is only `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the character for the sake of comparison, and know it will be at the end of a line, then when you read the word into your buffer, do a `strchr()` for `\n` and then replace that position with `\0` if you find it.

Comment: The result of `fgets()` does not always end with `"\n"`.  Long lines are only partially read will not have it.  The last line in the file may not either.  `strchr()` works when a test for a return value of `NULL` is added.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
size_t length = strlen(dictionaryWord);
if (length > 0 && dictionaryWord[length-1] == '\n') {
    dictionaryWord[length-1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice: (I prefer `dictionaryWord[--length] = 0;` as then `length` is useful for later code.).  Both get the job done.